# What practical use is dropDuplicates in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Consider the following data frame:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=[64, 2]), columns=['id', 'key'])
pdf['value'] = pdf['key'].apply(lambda v: 'value--%d' % v)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

It is [well](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26767?jql=text%20%7E%20%22dropduplicates%22) [documented](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25420) that drop duplicates will result in non-deterministic behaviour here:

```
df.dropDuplicates(subset=['id']).orderBy('id').show()
+---+---+--------+
| id|key|   value|
+---+---+--------+
|  0|  3|value--3|
...

df.dropDuplicates(subset=['id']).orderBy('id').show()
+---+---+--------+
| id|key|   value|
+---+---+--------+
|  0|  0|value--0| <--- Picked some random row
...
```

The reason for this is that when partitioning over `subset` no sort order is defined.

To remove this non-deterministic behaviour, you must use a window function:

```
sort_window = Window.partitionBy(['id']).orderBy(['key']) <-- Explicitly choose sort order in window
df.withColumn('rank', row_number().over(sort_window)).filter('rank == 1').drop('rank').orderBy('id').show()
+---+---+--------+
| id|key|   value|
+---+---+--------+
|  0|  0|value--0| <--- Always picks the same row
...
```

If you wish to select distinct values from a specific column subset, the `distinct` function also exists, eg. `df.select('id','key').distinct()`.

However, the spark developers continue to [close issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26767) relating to this as 'expected behaviour', and have faithfully added it to the [spark 3 api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates).

So... here's my actual question:

It seems fantastically broken to have this broken API function, that does the wrong thing in every circumstance I can imagine. For selecting subsets `distinct` is the correct method to use, and in
all other circumstances, the use of `dropDuplicates` results in undefined non-deterministic behaviour,
which is highly undesirable in data processing workloads.

Am I missing something?

In what circumstances is it *ever useful* to use `dropDuplicates`?

Comment: `distinct()` doesn't let you find duplicates by a subset of columns, does it?

Comment: @ernest_k `.select(*cols).distinct()`; you could argue the api is trivially easier, but it is meaningfully distinct to do the above vs. `.dropDuplicates(subset=cols).select(*cols)`. I'd argue the latter is actually more verbose and less obvious.

Comment: Not arguing your main point, but what you have there is not the same thing as `.dropDuplicates(subset=cols)`, which preserves the full schema.

Comment: ...but my point is that the data in the rest of the schema is rubbish after you've done this, so does that actually achieve anything? How is that ever practically useful?

Comment: Exactly, I'm not arguing that point. My opinion, though, is that you expect more than `dropDuplicates` was designed to do. If those rows are truly "duplicates", then *any* single one of them is as good as the others (and it would be a bit arbitrary to deem the result of this as rubbish)

Comment: I think it's not arbitrary at all to suggest that an ambiguous results from a query are problematic. However, I don't really want to create an epic comment thread here to argue the point; post an answer if you have a meaningful one please~

Comment: Nope, I it was merely an opinion on how this is asked, not an answer. Just for clarity, the issue you linked to ([SPARK-26767](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26767), and the ones that one is related to) is about duplicates not being identified consistently across repeated calls (and I'd agree that this is a major issue). Your post seems to ask only about the ordering, or just which duplicate is retained. Mind confirming whether SPARK-26767 is in fact related to your problem?

Comment: @ernest_k it's the same issue; this is literally the identical problem to what I encountered. The result of the dropDuplicates is ambiguous, so the filter results in different counts every run. This is a perfect example of where the API results in surprising behaviour.  The only *meaningful* result of the dropDuplicates() in that issue would be `select('colA', 'colB', 'colC')` but the user is running the filter `...and colG='G' and colH='H')...` which is *meaningless* because the data in G and H is ambiguous. This is exactly what I'm referring to in my comments.